# Asset Catalog, is it ok to add only 1x image and ignore 2x and 3x images?

Tags: ios, iphone, asset-catalog

When I open the asset catalog I can see for each image I have 3 variants: 1x, 2x and 3x

[image]

But I only have my images in the 4x variants (ex physical dimension of 864x564 for a display dimension of 216x141), and I would like to avoid to resize them. how could I do? for example, just set it (so with a dimension of 864x564) in the 1x and let the iPhone resize it at runtime?

Comment: 2x is probably still the most commonly used resolution. Note that a 2x image is 4 times smaller (in pixels) than a 4x image. That means that if you use oversized images, the assets in you app bundle will be at least 4 times as big, the app will have to store them in memory (which will eat a lot of memory), resize them at runtime (which will eat performance) and the user will only see the resized image anyway.
Why don't you want to resize the asset?

Comment: @Sulthan ok thanks :) you are right! but in theory nothing forbid me to put my 864x564 picture in the 1x and just use this 1x image right ?

Comment: @loki - yes, if you have only one image, just put it in the 1x spot.

Comment: There is actually the option to use only one scale (see the "Scales" dropdown).

Comment: @Sulthan prfect answer exactly what i was looking for :)